# Query with two different where conditions

Tags: sql

I have a table **books** where users donate number of books:

```
 username   books  date
 ____________________________________ 
 Jon        3      2017-06-12
 Jon        2      2017-05-20
 Mary       4      2017-05-12
```

I want something like

```
username    This month   Previous Month
_______________________________________________
Jon           3                2
```

Comment: Which DBMS you are using ?

Comment: Please read [ask] and show what you have tried. `GROUP BY` and `DATEPART` will get you quite far.

Comment: And to the upvoter: you as well should read [ask]. Don't pity-upvote incomplete questions.

Comment: @CodeCaster - And to you don't suggest something before knowing the full details. `DATEPART` does not work in all DBMS

Comment: @CodeCaster The question is quite clear. There's no requirement that a question need to show what's been tried so far.

Comment: What happened to Mary? Please explain the logic

Comment: @nos I don't want to go and hold a discussion that has been held on Meta plenty of times already, but check the tooltips for the vote arrows.

Comment: Which DBMS? What have you tried?  There is nothing much we can help if you don't give enough info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need some kind of grouping or conditional `sum` operations.  The simplest way to get the result in your question - though which may not actually scale to your needs - is:

```
select username
      ,sum(case when dateadd(datediff(month,0,[date]),0) = dateadd(datediff(month,0,getdate()),0) then books else 0 end as ThisMonth
      ,sum(case when dateadd(datediff(month,0,[date]),0) = dateadd(datediff(month,0,getdate())-1,0) then books else 0 end as PreviousMonth
from books
where username = 'Jon'
group by username
```

Obviously with more details in your question you could get a better suited answer and one that is not specific to SQL Server should you be on a different DBMS.  That said, the conditional and date logic is the same in all other DBMS implementations, you may just need to change the function names.

This works by adding the number of months between an arbitrary start date (the `0`s in the functions above) and a date value to get the date at the start of the month.  The dates returned by this logic for both your `date` value and today (the `getdate()` function) will return the same start of the month where they are both within the same calendar month.  By adding one less month (the `-1` in the script above) you get the start of last month, which you can then also compare to your `date` value to get the number of `books` for last month.

The `sum` and `group by` is there to 'flatten' your data into the one row per `username` value.